# Which Android emulator could be configured to use Socks proxy?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

There are many **Windows** applications that are configurable to use `Socks proxy` . For example **Telegram** messenger or `Android Studio` or **FireFox** browser ( by using some plugins ) or **Google Chrome browser** ( by using some plugins ) .

Between `Android` emulators in **Windows OS** ( For example Genymotion or Memu or Nox or BlueStacks or `Android Studio` Virtual Device or .... ) , Which one could be configurable to use **Socks proxy** ?

For example I know that `Android Studio` Virtual Device has options in its settings that we could use `HTTP` proxy in it . I am searching for `Android emulators` that could be configurable to use `Socks proxy` .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use Proxifier to pass all Internet traffic of our Windows PC through a Socks proxy . For this , we should set IP address and port number of our Socks proxy in Proxifier as well as we should go to Name Resolution section of app and then go to DNS Setting and set "Resolve hostnames through proxy" option active .
Now all Internet traffic of our Windows PC that include all Internet traffic of our Android emulators pass through our Socks proxy .